# Avoid Show create table - Mysql General Logs

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm trying to enable the **mysql.general_log** options in mysql.ini file. But my log files prints like below,

```
1 Query SHOW CREATE TABLE `crm_user`
1 Query SELECT * FROM `crm_user` `t` WHERE g_user_id =1021271;
```

Can anyone explain how to avoid the "SHOW CREATE TABLE `crm_user`" line on each select query in log file ?